# I've overridden twig exceptions page but it only shows on dev pages, not prod

Tags: symfony

I've created custom error page:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig
```

I've cleared cache but it still only appears on Dev pages. prod shows ugly "Oops! An Error Occurred" message which may or may not be a apache default page. Any ideas how to enable these custom error pages in prod environment too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exception_full.html.twig` is used only in dev environment.

In prod you have to use `error.html.twig` or `error404.html.twig` (this one is good when you want to customize specific error).

That is because more info needed to be shown in dev environment. In prod environment you wouldn't want to show all that info (logs, trace, etc.) that you are showing in dev environment. And that's why another template is used in prod.

Comment: That worked with 404 pages, but other errors are still blank and error.html.twig is still not used. I even tried error500.html.twig with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: @Leo, try to monitor logs and find out why it can't find needed template.